# Push Item into Stack with C

Tags: c, pointers, stack, push, singly-linked-list

this is my push function, which takes in a stack and an int a parameters, turns the int into part of a stackNode and returns a new stack with the added new node (StackNode and Stack have already been properly initialized):

```
Stack push(Stack stk,int data){
    struct StackNode *top = stk.top;
    struct StackNode *node;
    node->data = data;
    node->nextNode = top;
    stk.top = node;
    stk.count++;
    return stk;
}
```

The problem I am having is that each time I run the push function, it over writes other StackNode items in the stack as the parameter I ran.

For example:

```
push(stk, 3): stack output = 3 //good so far
push (stk, 4): stack output= 4 4//the correct output would be 3 4!
push(stk, 56): stack out put= 56 56 56 //what's going on!
```

what am I doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 3):

You did not allocate memory for the node. Add the memory allocation.

```
Stack push(Stack stk,int data){
    struct StackNode *top = stk.top;
    struct StackNode *node = malloc( sizeof( struct StackNode ) );

    node->data = data;
    node->nextNode = top;
    stk.top = node;
    stk.count++;

    return stk;
}
```

Or you can add a check of a successful allocation.

```
Stack push(Stack stk,int data){
    struct StackNode *top = stk.top;
    struct StackNode *node = malloc( sizeof( struct StackNode ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->nextNode = top;
        stk.top = node;
        stk.count++;
    }

    return stk;
}
```

I suppose that initially the data member `top` of the object of the type `Stack` was initialized by NULL.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! the malloc thing worked!! Can you please explain it to me? My prof did a bad job of teaching it

Comment: @ashadeka You need to allocate a node where you are going to store the value of the variable data and also the reference to the next node. The list is a chain of nodes joined by pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:
  //You can assume that the function call passes the: address of a pointer to the node at the top of the stack, and an integer. ion: e.g.  push (&stackpointer, 5)
// insert a node with data value 5 onto the top of a stack

```
void fun(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info)  
{ 
   StackNodePtr  *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));


   if (newPtr != NULL) {           
      newPtr->data = info;           
     newPtr->nextPtr = *topPtr;
      *topPtr = newPtr;              
   }                     
   else { // no space available
      printf("%d not inserted. No memory available.\n", info);
   } 
}
```

}

Comment: Does CoderGirl94 mean that you are a girlfriend of the 94th Coder?:)

Comment: are you flirting on my question

Answer (score -1):

I read you code this way

```
struct StackNode *node;
node->nextNode = stk.top;
stk.top = node;
```

it looks like you adding a node but the reference on next is always on itself.

Edit:

```
struct StackNode *top = stk.top;
struct StackNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
node->data = data;
top->nextNode = node;
stk.top = node;
stk.count++;
return stk;
```

Edit2:

Sry to forget to explain,

you wrote

```
node->nextNode = top;
```

that I replaced with

```
top->nextNode = node;
```

Your code has tacken the new node and referenced the current top as the next one and then made the new one the top, that means as you called the stack, the beginning node was the node, that you put on your stack last and it reffered to itself as the next node, hence this output:

```
push(stk, 3): stack output = 3 //good so far
push (stk, 4): stack output= 4 4//the correct output would be 3 4!
push(stk, 56): stack out put= 56 56 56 //what's going on!
```

My code changed that to, that if your put a new node on the stack, the new one is defined as the next node of the current top node, before defining the new node the new top node.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! the malloc thing worked!! Can you please explain it to me? My prof did a bad job of teaching it

Comment: `top->nextNode = node;` : Destroy the list.