# C stack implementation using structures

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, stack

my professor doesn't explain much and just gives tasks to complete. I saw similar task here [Push Item into Stack with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946691/push-item-into-stack-with-c) ,but I wish I could see full code, since I don't understand what top and node refers to.

```
typedef struct Stack
    {
        int* array;
        int size;

    }Stack;

void initStack(Stack *s)
{
    s->size = 0;
    s->array = NULL;

}
```

Don't change parameters in this function. I spent few hours reading different articles , but I still cant seem to understand how it works and how correctly raise size,allocate memory when value is inputed and how stack values on top of each other. Thank you.

```
void push(Stack *s, int data){

    Stack* m = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    m->array = value;
    m->size = 1;
    s = m;

    printf("%d %d",s->size,s->array);
}
```

Comment: This `push()` function is problematic, modified `s` is never returned.

Comment: I am very dumb, but I dont need to return anything, I just need to push values. Also int data and value I mean the same, but I tried changing so many things I didnt see a mistake there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function

```
void push(Stack *s, int data){

    Stack* m = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    m->array = value;
    m->size = 1;
    s = m;

    printf("%d %d",s->size,s->array);
}
```

does not make any sense and has undefined behavior due to this statement

```
m->array = value;
```

and a memory leak due to this statement

```
s = m;
```

What you need is something like

```
int push( Stack *s, int data )
{
    int *p = realloc( s->array, ( s->size + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        s->array = p;
        s->array[s->size] = data;
        ++s->size;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Stack
    {
        int* array;
        int size;

    }Stack;

void initStack(Stack *s)
{
    s->size = 0;
    s->array = NULL;

}

int push( Stack *s, int data )
{
    int *p = realloc( s->array, ( s->size + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        s->array = p;
        s->array[s->size] = data;
        ++s->size;
    }

    return success;
}


int main(void) 
{
    Stack s;

    initStack( &s );

    push( &s, 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes about value I noticed only now, I changed code a lot and didnt notice, sorry. Thank you now it looks pretty simple.